# "Scan interface error" when connecting to a DB2 database restored on a different server

Tags: db2, restore

I restored a database backup taken on a different server using this script:

```
FORCE APPLICATIONS ALL;
RESTORE DATABASE MY_DATABASE_NAME
    FROM /backup/db2inst1 
    TAKEN AT 20140104051657 
    ON /data 
    INTO MY_DATABASE_NAME 
    WITH 2 BUFFERS 
    BUFFER 1024 
    PARALLELISM 1 
    WITHOUT PROMPTING;
TERMINATE;
```

From which I receive the message:

```
 Restore is successful
```

Then I try to connect:

```
[db2inst1@host sql]$ db2 CONNECT TO MY_DATABASE_NAME
SQL0901N  The SQL statement or command failed because of a database system
error. (Reason "Scan interface error".)  SQLSTATE=58004
```

I was able to restore the exact same backup to the server it came from with no problems.  This only occurs when attempting to restore it to a different server.  The second server has a nearly identical setup (both CentOS 6.3, both using db2 10.1 express-C), the only difference being the main server has a user db2inst1 in group db2iadm1 and the second has db2inst1 in group db2inst1.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know which fix pack both versions were on? I found this APAR list which mentions the error if you move from FP1 back to the GA release of 10.1: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC85565. It looks from what I'm seeing elsewhere on the web that this can result if you restore from a newer version of DB2 to an older version (possibly even fix pack-wise) such as the link above shows. Check to make sure both are at the same FP level to rule out the problem.

Comment: I ran across that same article. I am in the process of updating to 10.5 which has the added benefit of 16G memory (up from 4).  I will update this question with the results, but as of this comment the restore has been running for more than 4 hours (trying to restore on my development laptop VM with 1G ram)...

Comment: @ChrisAldrich, the update to 10.5 did the trick.  It doesn't really explain the problem, but nonetheless it worked.  If you would like to change your comment to an answer, I would be happy to mark it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know which fix pack both versions were on? I found this [APAR list](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC85565) which mentions the error if you move from FP1 back to the GA release of 10.1. It looks from what I'm seeing elsewhere on the web that this can result if you restore from a newer version of DB2 to an older version (possibly even fix pack-wise) such as the link above shows. Check to make sure both are at the same FP level to rule out the problem.